# PHP Which music is most popular (comparing strings)

Tags: php

Hey guys trying to find a more efficient way to do the following. 
I am tracking users video history on my site, i have multiple videos on this site all with similar 'Genres'; Rock, Pop, Acoustic, Alternative etc etc.

What i am doing is grabbing the last six videos that the user has watched, (depending on if they have watched six videos) and finding the genre that relates to that video. once i have six genres;

E.g

```
$Genre1 = "Pop"; //The last video watched
$Genre2 = "Rock"; //The second last video watched
$Genre3 = "Rock"; // ect ect
$Genre4 = "Alternative";
$Genre5 = "Rock";
$Genre5 = "Rock";
```

Rock is the most popular Genre type out of these results and i am wondering if there is a way to find out which genre is popular.

Comment: Put them in an array and use `array_count_values`. Then sort the resulting array to find the most popular.

Comment: If you are tracking that in a database it is more practical and likely more performant to just write a query doing that for you instead of pulling every user's six last videos into PHP.

Comment: saw title - thought "dire straits" rocks - there is a good set of strings. Well it was money for nothing

Answer (score 0):

Compose an array from all these strings, e.g.:

```
$genres = array('pop', 'rock', 'rock', 'alt', 'rock', 'rock');
```

and than use `array_count_values($genres)` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Genre[] = "Pop"; //The last video watched
$Genre[] = "Rock"; //The second last video watched
$Genre[] = "Rock"; // ect ect
$Genre[] = "Alternative";
$Genre[] = "Rock";
$Genre[] = "Rock";

$popular = array_count_values($Genre);
$popular = rsort($popular);
foreach ($popular as $pop) {
    $most_pop = $pop;
    break;
}

echo $pop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have multiple variables for the same thing like this, you should see it as a clue to use some form of array. You can then look at the PHP manual for useful array functions to act on your data.

In this case, one useful trick is to put your genres as the *keys* of an associative array, with values counting the occurrences of that genre, like this:

```
array(
    'Rock'  => 2,
    'Jazz'  => 1,
    'Blues' => 3
)
```

You can build this up in a loop with code like `$scoreboard[$genre]++` (where `$scoreboard` is the array you're building).

Once you have it, you can use [`sort()`](http://php.net/sort) to put it in order of scores, for instance.

I'll let you come up with your own solution rather than writing all the code for you, but hopefully this shows you how to tackle the problem.